# Imageresizer.net not resizing image coming from the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image-processing, image-resizing, imageresizer

I'm using the imageresizer plugin from http://imageresizing.net/. 
The website i'm working on (an asp.net mvc5 application) contains some static images located in the /content/images folder in the root of the website.
The second part of the images is coming from the database through an MVC-controller. The static images are being resized without any problems, but the images coming from the database aren't being resized using this very same plugin.

I've created a controller called 'ImagesController' and mapped the url like 'images/'. 
So the url could be like this;

```
http://localhost:55062/images/47cff4e6-8932-48dc-8baf-f328e89f3f83
```

When I make a request to this url i'm seeing my image correctly (in it's original size ofcourse), so no problems so far. So I've decided to add a with and height, and for testing purposes I also want to allow upscaling. So i'm making a request to the following url;

```
http://localhost:55062/images/47cff4e6-8932-48dc-8baf-f328e89f3f83?width=100&height=100&scale=both
```

The original size of the image behind this url is 2000 x 1334 pixels. So resizing it down to 100 x 100 pixels doesn't seem a problem to me. However, i'm seeing the image in it's original size.

A random static image on the url below is being resized without any problem;

```
http://localhost:55062/images/47cff4e6-8932-48dc-8baf-f328e89f3f83
```

What could this possibly be? I've already tried adding an extension to the url with the guid and i've also added a handler to the web.config so that .jpg urls are being ran through the .net pipeline, but unfortunately this doesn't help either. I'm quite stuck on this issue for a few hours now, so hopefully somebody can help me out on this?

The imageresizing.net debugging info is shown here: http://notepad.cc/gaxafe38

Comment: I seem to recall that once the request is being processed by the controller, it's past the point in the request where ImageResizer does it's work. Have you tried using the SqlReader plugin?

Comment: No I haven't, will look into it. Sounds like a possible solution. Thanks for the response anyway.

Comment: @TiesonT. This indeed was the solution. Thanks! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from TiestonT I was able to solve the problem using the [SqlReader plugin](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/sqlreader).